# How do I animate steam from a coffee cup in my SVG icon code?

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I'm a graphic designer just learning about SVG animated icons and coding. I have illustrated a cup of coffee in illustrator then exported it as an SVG file. I am trying to animate the steam so that it rises like real steam. The problem is that it's not animating the steam even if I have .steam1 .st1 selected in CSS. I might just be really confused from the amount of tutorials I've been looking at. Could someone look at my HTML code for the illustration and help me properly animate it using CSS based off of this code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DLmCn

Here is my SVG code in HTML http://codepen.io/anon/pen/niHCA

```
<body> 
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="icon" 
     width="284px" height="284px" viewBox="0 0 64 64" 
     style="enable-background:new 0 0 64 64;" xml:space="preserve">



<style type="text/css">
<![CDATA[
    .st0{fill:#49331B;}
    .st1{fill:#E6E7E8;}
    .st2{opacity:0.8;fill:url(#SVGID_4_);}
    .st3{opacity:0.8;fill:url(#SVGID_5_);}
    .st4{fill:#F3E8C3;stroke:#F3E8C3;stroke-width:0.9486;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st5{fill:none;stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-width:0.4743;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st6{fill:#F3E8C3;}
    .st7{fill:#F4EFE9;}
    .st8{fill:#F79F63;}
    .st9{fill:url(#SVGID_1_);}
    .st10{fill:url(#SVGID_3_);}
    .st11{opacity:0.7;}
    .st12{fill:#307BA5;}
    .st13{fill:#328AC6;}
    .st14{fill:none;stroke:#E2D5B7;stroke-width:0.9486;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st15{opacity:0.5;fill:url(#SVGID_2_);}
    .st16{opacity:0.5;fill:url(#SVGID_6_);}
    .st17{fill:#77593D;}
]]>
</style>
<rect x="0.1" class="st8" width="64" height="64"/>
<linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="10.5957" y1="55.7451" x2="45.3627" y2="53.0889">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#F79F63"/>
    <stop  offset="5.723715e-03" style="stop-color:#F49E63"/>
    <stop  offset="0.1092" style="stop-color:#D88B57"/>
    <stop  offset="0.2279" style="stop-color:#C77F4F"/>
    <stop  offset="0.3712" style="stop-color:#BB7849"/>
    <stop  offset="0.5626" style="stop-color:#B47347"/>
    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#B27246"/>
</linearGradient>
<path class="st9" d="M45.4,54.4c0-0.4-0.3-0.9-0.8-1.3c-2.2-1.7-8.8-2.9-16.6-2.9c-9.6,0-17.4,1.8-17.4,4.1c0,2.3,7.8,4.1,17.4,4.1
    C37.6,58.5,45.4,56.7,45.4,54.4z"/>
<path class="st6" d="M43.8,32.9c3.5,0,6.4,3,6.4,6.7s-2.9,6.7-6.4,6.7 M44,49.9c5.4,0,9.8-4.6,9.8-10.3S49.4,29.2,44,29.2"/>
<linearGradient id="SVGID_2_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="43.7656" y1="39.6279" x2="51.1113" y2="39.6279">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#F3E8C3"/>
    <stop  offset="0.5114" style="stop-color:#F0E5BF"/>
    <stop  offset="0.6956" style="stop-color:#E6DBB6"/>
    <stop  offset="0.8269" style="stop-color:#D8CCA7"/>
    <stop  offset="0.9323" style="stop-color:#C6BA93"/>
    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#B6AA83"/>
</linearGradient>
<path class="st15" d="M43.9,46.8c4.3,0,7.2-2.5,7.2-7.2s-3.1-7-7.3-7l1.6,0.6c2.8,0.7,4.8,3.4,4.8,6.5s-1.9,5.7-4.8,6.5"/>
<path class="st4" d="M45,22.7c0-1.8-6.2-3.3-13.8-3.3s-13.8,1.5-13.8,3.3v31.4V54c0,1.8,6.2,3.3,13.8,3.3S45,55.8,45,54v0.1V22.7z"
    />
<ellipse class="st0" cx="31.2" cy="22.7" rx="13.3" ry="2.6"/>
<path class="st5" d="M27.8,21.4"/>
<path class="st5" d="M21.5,22.4"/>
<path class="st17" d="M33.9,20.8c5.5,0,8.9,0.8,8.9,1.9c0,0.5-1,1-2.6,1.3C40.2,24,48,21.9,33.9,20.8z"/>
<linearGradient id="SVGID_3_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="18.9062" y1="21.7559" x2="32.2139" y2="22.6411">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#382717"/>
    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#49331B"/>
</linearGradient>
<path class="st10" d="M22,24.6c0,0-3.8-3.2,14.2-4.4c0,0-9.2-0.8-15.7,0.9c0,0-4,0.9-2.1,2.3C18.4,23.4,20.1,24.3,22,24.6z"/>
<path class="st14" d="M45,22.5c0,1.8-6.2,3.3-13.8,3.3s-13.8-1.5-13.8-3.3"/>
<path class="st14" d="M45,22.7c0-1.8-6.2-3.3-13.8-3.3s-13.8,1.5-13.8,3.3"/>
<g>
    <path class="st7" d="M40.3,24.9c0,0-0.3,0.1-0.8,0.2c-0.5,0.1-1.2,0.3-2,0.4c-0.9,0.1-1.9,0.3-2.9,0.3C33.5,26,32.3,26,31.2,26
        c-1.2-0.1-2.3-0.1-3.4-0.2c-0.5,0-1.1-0.1-1.6-0.1c-0.5-0.1-1-0.2-1.4-0.2c-1.7-0.3-2.8-0.6-2.8-0.6s1.2,0.1,2.9,0.3
        c0.4,0,0.9,0.1,1.4,0.2c0.5,0,1,0,1.6,0c1.1,0,2.2,0.1,3.4,0.1c1.1,0,2.3,0,3.4-0.1c0.5,0,1.1-0.1,1.5-0.1c0.5,0,1-0.1,1.4-0.1
        c0.4,0,0.8-0.1,1.2-0.1c0.3,0,0.7-0.1,0.9-0.1C40.1,25,40.3,24.9,40.3,24.9z"/>
</g>
<linearGradient id="SVGID_4_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="45.3652" y1="31.4702" x2="46.6709" y2="31.4702">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#B6AA83"/>
    <stop  offset="0.2623" style="stop-color:#BEB28B"/>
    <stop  offset="0.6699" style="stop-color:#D6CAA4"/>
    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#F3E8C3"/>
</linearGradient>
<path class="st2" d="M45.4,29.3c0,0,1.1,0.2,1.3,0.3v4c0,0-0.9-0.4-1.3-0.5V29.3z"/>
<linearGradient id="SVGID_5_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="45.3652" y1="47.7295" x2="46.5889" y2="47.7295">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#B6AA83"/>
    <stop  offset="0.2623" style="stop-color:#BEB28B"/>
    <stop  offset="0.6699" style="stop-color:#D6CAA4"/>
    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#F3E8C3"/>
</linearGradient>
<path class="st3" d="M45.4,49.9c0,0,0.5-0.1,1.2-0.4v-3.9c0,0-0.3,0.2-1.2,0.5V49.9z"/>
<linearGradient id="SVGID_6_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="17.4443" y1="39.4248" x2="31.32" y2="41.6584">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#787157"/>
    <stop  offset="9.336331e-02" style="stop-color:#837B5F"/>
    <stop  offset="0.2765" style="stop-color:#A09674"/>
    <stop  offset="0.3167" style="stop-color:#A79C79"/>
    <stop  offset="0.6669" style="stop-color:#CDC29E"/>
    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#F3E8C3"/>
</linearGradient>
<path class="st16" d="M32.8,26.3l-6.2,31.3c0,0-9-0.4-9.6-3.5l0-31.6C17,22.5,16.1,26.2,32.8,26.3z"/>
<g>
    <g>
        <path class="st12" d="M22.9,41.4c0,0,0,0.1,0,0.1c0,0.1,0,0.1,0,0.2c0,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3c0,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3
            c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.2s-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.1c-0.2,0-0.4-0.1-0.5-0.2c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.2c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3
            c0-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3c0-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.2c0-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.1c0.1-0.8,0.1-1.5,0.2-2.3c0-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.2-0.6
            c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.2c0.1,0,0.2-0.1,0.4,0c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.4,0.1c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2
            c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.4c0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.5c0,0.1,0,0.2-0.1,0.3c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.2-0.1
            c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3c0-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3c0-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2c0,0-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1c0,0-0.1,0-0.1,0c0,0-0.1,0-0.1,0
            c0,0-0.1,0-0.1,0.1c0,0-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1s-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.3c-0.1,0.8-0.1,1.5-0.2,2.3c0,0,0,0,0,0c0,0,0,0,0,0.1c0,0,0,0.1,0,0.1
            c0,0,0,0.1,0,0.1c0,0,0,0.1,0.1,0.1c0,0,0,0,0.1,0.1c0,0,0.1,0,0.2,0.1c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.2,0c0,0,0.1,0,0.1-0.1
            c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2c0-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2c0,0,0,0,0-0.1c0,0,0-0.1,0-0.1c0,0,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1s0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1
            c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.2,0.1c0,0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1C22.9,41.3,22.9,41.3,22.9,41.4z"/>
        <path class="st12" d="M25.9,41.6c0,0,0,0.1,0,0.1c0,0.1,0,0.1,0,0.2c0,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3c0,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3
            c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.2c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.1s-0.4-0.1-0.5-0.1c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.2c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.3
            s-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3c0-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.2c0-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.1c0.1-0.8,0.1-1.5,0.2-2.3c0-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.1-0.6c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.3,0.2-0.3
            c0.2-0.2,0.4-0.3,0.7-0.2c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.4,0.1c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2s0.2,0.2,0.2,0.4c0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.5
            C26,40,25.9,40.8,25.9,41.6z M25.1,42C25.1,41.9,25.1,41.9,25.1,42c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1-0.2s0-0.1,0-0.1c0,0,0-0.1,0-0.1
            c0,0,0,0,0,0c0-0.8,0.1-1.6,0.1-2.3c0-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3c0-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2c0,0-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1c0,0-0.1,0-0.1,0
            c0,0-0.1,0-0.1,0c0,0-0.1,0-0.1,0.1c0,0-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1c0,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3c0,0.8-0.1,1.5-0.1,2.3c0,0,0,0,0,0c0,0,0,0,0,0.1
            s0,0.1,0,0.1c0,0,0,0.1,0,0.1c0,0,0,0.1,0.1,0.1c0,0,0,0,0.1,0.1c0,0,0.1,0,0.2,0C24.9,42.1,25,42.1,25.1,42
            C25.1,42,25.1,42,25.1,42z"/>
        <path class="st12" d="M29,42.3c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3c0,0.1,0,0.2-0.1,0.3c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1c-0.5,0-1,0-1.5,0
            c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.2-0.1c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3c0.1-1.3,0.1-2.6,0.2-4c0-0.1,0-0.2,0.1-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1
            c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.2,0.1c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3c0,1.2-0.1,2.4-0.1,3.6c0.4,0,0.8,0,1.1,0C28.8,42.2,28.9,42.2,29,42.3z"/>
        <path class="st13" d="M32.3,42.3c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3s0,0.2-0.1,0.3c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1c-0.5,0-1,0-1.5,0
            c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.2-0.1c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3c0-1.3,0-2.6,0-4c0-0.1,0-0.2,0.1-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1
            c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.2,0.1c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3c0,1.2,0,2.4,0,3.6c0.4,0,0.8,0,1.1,0C32.1,42.2,32.2,42.2,32.3,42.3z"/>
        <path class="st13" d="M35.4,42.2c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3c0,0.1,0,0.2-0.1,0.3c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1c-0.5,0-0.9,0-1.4,0
            c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.2-0.1c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3c0-1.3-0.1-2.6-0.1-4c0-0.1,0-0.2,0.1-0.3s0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1c0.4,0,0.9,0,1.3,0
            c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.2,0.1c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3c0,0.1,0,0.2-0.1,0.3c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1c-0.3,0-0.7,0-1,0c0,0.5,0,1,0,1.5
            c0.2,0,0.5,0,0.7,0c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.2,0.1c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3c0,0.1,0,0.2-0.1,0.3c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1
            c-0.2,0-0.5,0-0.7,0c0,0.3,0,0.7,0,1c0.3,0,0.7,0,1,0C35.3,42.1,35.3,42.2,35.4,42.2z"/>
        <path class="st13" d="M38.6,41.6c0,0.1,0,0.1,0,0.2c0,0.1,0,0.2-0.1,0.3c0,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.2
            c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.1c-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.5-0.1c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.3c0-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3
            c0-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.2s0-0.1,0-0.1c0-0.8-0.1-1.5-0.1-2.3c0-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.6c0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.4c0.2-0.2,0.4-0.3,0.7-0.3
            c0.3,0,0.5,0.1,0.7,0.2c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.3c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.6c0,0.1,0,0.2-0.1,0.3c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1
            c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.2-0.1c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.3c0-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.2c0-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1c0,0-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1c0,0-0.1,0-0.1,0
            c0,0-0.1,0-0.1,0c0,0-0.1,0-0.1,0.1c0,0-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2c0,0.1,0,0.2,0,0.3c0,0.8,0.1,1.6,0.1,2.3c0,0,0,0,0,0c0,0,0,0,0,0.1
            c0,0,0,0.1,0,0.1s0,0.1,0,0.1c0,0,0,0.1,0.1,0.1c0,0,0,0,0.1,0.1c0,0,0.1,0,0.2,0c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.2-0.1c0,0,0.1,0,0.1-0.1
            c0,0,0-0.1,0.1-0.1c0,0,0-0.1,0-0.1c0,0,0-0.1,0-0.1c0,0,0-0.1,0-0.1c0,0,0,0,0,0c0-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.6c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.2,0
            c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.2-0.1c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2c0-0.1,0-0.2,0.1-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1c0.3,0,0.6,0,0.9-0.1
            c0,0.4,0.1,0.9,0.1,1.3C38.6,41.5,38.6,41.5,38.6,41.6z"/>
        <path class="st13" d="M41.6,41.8c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2c0,0.1,0,0.2-0.1,0.3s-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1c-0.5,0-0.9,0.1-1.4,0.1
            c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.2-0.1c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2c-0.1-1.3-0.2-2.6-0.3-4c0-0.1,0-0.2,0.1-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1
            c0.4,0,0.9-0.1,1.3-0.1c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.2,0.1c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2c0,0.1,0,0.2-0.1,0.3c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1
            c-0.3,0-0.7,0.1-1,0.1c0,0.5,0.1,1,0.1,1.5c0.2,0,0.5,0,0.7-0.1c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.2,0.1c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2c0,0.1,0,0.2-0.1,0.3
            c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1c-0.2,0-0.5,0-0.7,0.1c0,0.3,0.1,0.7,0.1,1c0.3,0,0.7-0.1,1-0.1C41.4,41.7,41.5,41.8,41.6,41.8z"/>
    </g>
</g>
<g class="steam1">
     <path class="st1" d="M39.1,20.8c0,0-0.2-0.1-0.6-0.3c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.3-0.6-0.5c-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.4-0.8-0.7c-0.2-0.3-0.5-0.6-0.7-1
        c-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.9-0.5-1.4c0-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.8c0-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.1-0.8c0.1-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.2-0.7c0.1-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.3-0.7
        c0.5-0.9,1.1-1.7,1.7-2.4c0.3-0.4,0.5-0.7,0.8-1.1c0.2-0.3,0.4-0.7,0.5-1c0.1-0.3,0.2-0.6,0.2-0.9c0.1-0.3,0-0.5,0-0.7
        C39.7,7.2,39.6,7,39.6,7s0,0.1,0.1,0.2c0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.2,0.5c0.1,0.2,0.2,0.5,0.2,0.8c0,0.3,0,0.7-0.1,1.1
        c-0.2,0.8-0.6,1.6-1.1,2.4c-0.5,0.8-1.1,1.6-1.6,2.4c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.4-0.3,0.6c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.5-0.2,0.6c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.1,0.6
        c0,0.2,0,0.4,0,0.6c0.1,0.4,0.1,0.8,0.3,1.2c0,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.2,0.5c0.1,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.5c0.4,0.6,0.8,1.1,1.1,1.4
        C38.9,20.6,39.1,20.8,39.1,20.8z"/>
    </g>

  <g class="steam2">
    <path class="st1" d="M25.9,17.9c0,0-0.2-0.1-0.6-0.3c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.3-0.6-0.5c-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.4-0.8-0.7c-0.3-0.3-0.5-0.6-0.7-1
        c-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.9-0.5-1.4c0-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.8c0-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.1-0.8c0.1-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.2-0.7c0.1-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.3-0.7
        c0.5-0.9,1.1-1.7,1.7-2.4c0.3-0.4,0.5-0.7,0.7-1.1c0.2-0.3,0.4-0.7,0.5-1c0.1-0.3,0.2-0.6,0.2-0.9c0.1-0.3,0-0.5,0-0.7
        c-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.7-0.1-0.7s0,0.1,0.1,0.2c0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.2,0.5c0.1,0.2,0.2,0.5,0.2,0.8c0,0.3,0,0.7-0.1,1.1
        c-0.2,0.8-0.6,1.6-1.1,2.4c-0.5,0.8-1.1,1.6-1.6,2.4c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.4-0.3,0.6c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.5-0.2,0.6c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.1,0.6
        c0,0.2,0,0.4,0,0.6c0.1,0.4,0.1,0.8,0.3,1.2c0,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.2,0.5c0.1,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.5c0.4,0.6,0.8,1.1,1.1,1.4
        C25.8,17.7,25.9,17.9,25.9,17.9z"/>
</g>

<g class="steam3">
    <path class="st1" d="M32.5,22.5c0,0-0.2-0.1-0.6-0.3c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.3-0.6-0.5c-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.4-0.8-0.7c-0.3-0.3-0.5-0.6-0.7-1
        c-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.9-0.5-1.4c0-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.8c0-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.1-0.8c0.1-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.2-0.7c0.1-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.3-0.7
        c0.5-0.9,1.1-1.7,1.7-2.4c0.3-0.4,0.5-0.7,0.7-1.1c0.2-0.3,0.4-0.7,0.5-1c0.1-0.3,0.2-0.6,0.2-0.9c0.1-0.3,0-0.5,0-0.7
        C33.1,8.9,33,8.7,33,8.7s0,0.1,0.1,0.2c0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.2,0.5c0.1,0.2,0.2,0.5,0.2,0.8c0,0.3,0,0.7-0.1,1.1
        c-0.2,0.8-0.6,1.6-1.1,2.4c-0.5,0.8-1.1,1.6-1.6,2.4c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.4-0.3,0.6c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.5-0.2,0.6c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.1,0.6
        c0,0.2,0,0.4,0,0.6c0.1,0.4,0.1,0.8,0.3,1.2c0,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.2,0.5c0.1,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.5c0.4,0.6,0.8,1.1,1.1,1.4
        C32.3,22.3,32.5,22.5,32.5,22.5z"/>
</g>
</svg>

  <script type=”text/javascript” src=”prefixfree.min.js”></script>
  </body>
```

Comment: Here's one example that a quick google search found: http://demo.web3designs.com/css-jquery-animated-hot-smoke-coffee-tea-effect.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a quick starting point based off of your code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rAdom?editors=101

First, define keyframes for the animation:

```
@keyframes steaming {
    0% {
      transform: translateY(0px);
      opacity: 0;
    }

    50% { opacity: 1; }

    100% {
      transform: translateY(-10px);
      opacity: 0;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes {
 ...
}
```

The steam will start off invisible (opacity: 0), then fade in (opacity: 1) and back out, as it moves up, as determined by translateY(-10px). Note the pixel values are scaled according to the SVG viewbox and height/width values.

Then, apply these keyframes to each of the steam SVG elements, using the classes you've set:

```
.steam1{
  -webkit-animation: steaming 7s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: steaming 7s linear infinite;
  animation: steaming 7s linear infinite;
}
```

You can adjust the animation speeds to make it look a bit better.

Comment: Thank you! But I think I'm still having a problem with the SVG elements. I put in the animation code into the CSS but nothing happens and "steam1" is the class for that steam. I noticed when I changed the 'g class' name under Steam1 (st1) that the steam turns black. I've tried .steam1 .st1 but that doesn't work either. Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind! I see you did it in the link! Thank you sooo much! I really appreciate this. I'm still learning so I appreciate any help even if I sound like I don't know what I'm doing. You rock.

Comment: I was looking for something just like this, and couldn't find it anywhere else. Thanks! :)